# Using VPN on host then Proxy on VMware guest?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, vmware-player

I have been working on the for 9 hours and I cannot find a solution. I want to run my VPN on my host computer and then use a proxy on the vmware machine. If I run the vpn through my host computer I get that VPN connection through the vm. But I cannot connect to a proxy on the vm while connected to the VPN on the host. Are there any solutions to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible,looks,like a loop without exit condition. You should try tails Operating system. Why don't you connect it in the reverse manner.. Is there is any special requirement to met, and also which os are you using now.

Comment: I am using windows 7 although I have tried on windows xp. If I would use it in a reverse manner would my location be the proxy's location or the VPN.

Comment: i think this will help you.. create a virtual network  adapter for vm player[ connection between internet and guest]. and the other adapter for your VPN[fot host]

Comment: I tried this and I don't see how I would do this. I made the one for the connection. But I don't know how to make a new on on the vpn.